# Add entry to table consisting only of parent model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, nested-forms

I have two models in an app: `Person` and `Director`; `person has_one director`.  A person can be many things (officer, contractor etc AND director); if they are a director I simply want to store their user id in the directors table and nothing more.

The table I set up therefore consists only of 4 columns:

```
mysql> show columns in directors;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| person_id  | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I would like each person entry on a form to have a nested radio button that creates an entry in the directors table if it's set to "Yes" and removes/doesn't create an entry if it's set to "No."  Seems simple but I'm realizing I have no idea how to do that, since the explicit value from the radio button wouldn't be saved to the database.

Is there a good way to pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `attr_accessor` to your `Person` model, such as `is_director`. This is a temporary attribute that will not be stored in the database. And then based on the value of `is_director`, you can have a callback to set the logic to make the user their own director.

```
class Person < ...
  ...

  attr_accessor :is_director
  after_create  :make_director

private

  def make_director
    if self.is_director
      #your logic to make the user their own director
    else
      #some other logic
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your form, you can add the radio buttons:

```
<%= f.label :is_director %><br />
<%= f.label :is_director, "Yes", :value => "true"  %>
<%= f.radio_button :is_director, true, :checked => is_director?(@person)  %>
<%= f.label :is_director, "No", :value => "false" %>
<%= f.radio_button :is_director, false, :checked => !is_director?(@person) %>
```

Then you can create a helper in `persons_helper.rb`:

```
def is_director?(person)
  #whatever the logic is to check if a person is a director
end
```

You would also need to add `is_director` to the `permit` array of the strong params in your controller.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I spoke to soon; thought I had it working.  I'm getting an error: `undefined method id` and it's regarding the radio buttons in the view.

Comment: Updated the answer. Not sure what your logic would be to check if a person is a director but you can put it in the helper method.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'm currently troubleshooting the error `undefined method `parent_id` regarding the `set_person_id`.  If there's any obvious obvious reason for this error, I'd be all ears.

Comment: The idea behind the answer is to showcase the use of `attr_accessor` and callbacks. I am not not familiar with your code to answer the question fully. It is not clear why you need a separate directors table (for the way the table is built now). Why can't you just have a boolean field on the persons table to indicate if the user is a director or not? If you want the directors table to hold both the `person_id` and their `manager_id`, then you are missing the `manager_id` foreign key

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any other attributes that the different roles will need, it might make more sense to have a roles table that has records for director, officer, contractor, etc. instead of making them separate tables. This also keeps it flexible to add additional roles easily through an admin panel instead of through new tables and migrations.

Then you can have a joins table to allow a user to belong to one or more of those roles through either radio buttons or checkboxes.

User - has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
Role - has_and_belongs_to_many :users

```
<legend>Roles</legend>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline') %>
</div>
```

Make sure to allow :role_ids => [] in your controller's user_params